# Adding more than 1 thing into a Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For this program, I am supposed to add two different kinds of 'mirrors' (the forward and backward slashes represent mirrors in my game) which is '/' and '\'. I have successfully added the first set of slashes into my maze array but I can't seem to figure out how to add both of the different slashes at the same time.

```
public static void placeMirrors(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Promopting user for how many mirrors they want
    System.out.print("\nHow many mirrors do you want in your maze?");
    System.out.print("The maximum number of mirrors you can have is 8. The minimum is 2.\n");
    int usersMirrors = input.nextInt();

    // Deploying mirrors randomly within the maze
    for (int i = 1; i <= usersMirrors;) {
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * numRows);
        int y = (int)(Math.random() * numCols);

        // *FIGURE OUT ADDING BOTH SETS AT ONCE THING*
        if((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols) && (maze[x][y] == ".")) {
            maze[x][y] = "\\";
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Mirrors placed.");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mirrors", but there is one glaring error here, `maze[x][y] == "."`, although I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problems. Regardless, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add a second `if` inside the loop.  I assume you're adding the "mirrors" in pairs.

```
// Deploying mirrors randomly within the maze
for (int i = 1; i <= usersMirrors;) {
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * numRows);
    int y = (int)(Math.random() * numCols);

    if((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols) && (maze[x][y].equals( "." ) )) {
        maze[x][y] = "\\";
        i++;
    }

    x = (int)(Math.random() * numRows);
    y = (int)(Math.random() * numCols);

    if((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols) && (maze[x][y].equals( "." ) )) {
        maze[x][y] = "/";
    }
}
```